# Is there any animal database or website that classifies animals as wild / domestic?

Tags: zoology, botany, database, classification

Is there any animal database or website that classifies animals wild / domestic?

Or.. the site that I can get the wild / domestic information of animal list...

Comment: That’s a hard one. For many species, there are individuals that are wild/feral, and individuals that are domestic: cats, dogs, birds, snakes, lizards. iNaturalist has an option to indicate whether each *observation* is captive or cultivated, and that’s about it.

Comment: If we knew the purpose of the question we might be able to offer more help. There is a lot of grey area with domestication.

Comment: I need the list of wild animals for the project.. so I tried to get the database of the animal list which classifies wild / domestic.